# How to get data from related table with EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on web project, I created one-to-many relationship with code-first approach, between machine model and experiment model. Here is the code:

```
   public class Experiment
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Machine")]
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public Machine Machine { get; set; }
}


 public class Machine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Experiment> Experiments { get; set; }
}
```

I can take all of the experiments filter by userId:

```
  public async Task<IList<Experiment>> GetExperimentsAsync(int userId)
    {
        var experiments = await _experimentsDbContext.Experiments
                                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                .ToListAsync();

        return experiments; 
    }
```

But I receive machine = null, what I need to do is get list of experiments filter by userId and include related machine object, but I can't do this.

Comment: You need to get the data from the `Machine` table too.
Are you getting the `MachineId` value?

Comment: Yes, I store MachineId as ForeignKey in experiment table, so getting MachineId by executing the above code

Comment: Please read [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). Everything in EF core is well-documented.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify that you want to load related data by using the .Include() method.

Please have a look at the [MS documentation](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Example:

```
public async Task<IList<Experiment>> GetExperimentsAsync(int userId)
{
    var experiments = await _experimentsDbContext.Experiments
                            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                            .Include(e => e.Machine)
                            .ToListAsync();

    return experiments; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I have one more questions, can you tell me how to take  only Machine.Name property from Machine object? When I try to do it, I receive exception "Name" is not a navigation property.

Comment: It won't work on "Name", the .Include() method expects a navigation property i.e Machine in this case. Any reason why you only want the Name?

Comment: I need only Name on the client's side. When I invoke get method, i receive all data about the machine with ICollection<Experiments>, so returned JSON isn't clear and causes a problem on client side

Comment: In that case you could create a DTO object and return that instead. The MachineDTO object only having a name Property. return experiments.Select(e => new ExperimentDto {Machine = new MachineDto {Name = e.Machine.Name}});

Comment: Or mark the Properties that you don't want to serialize with the [JsonIgnore] attribute

Comment: [JsonIgnore] attribute was what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
public async Task<IList<Experiment>> GetExperimentsAsync(int userId)
{
    var experiments = await _experimentsDbContext.Experiments
                            .Include(experiment => experiment.Machine)
                            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                            .ToListAsync();
    return experiments; 
}
```